# Self-Consistent gap equation: numerical solution

Tags: computational-physics, superconductivity, software

I'm trying to calculate the simple self-consistent gap equation in Python.
$$\Delta = \lambda  \int_{-Ec}^{Ec} \Delta \frac{\tanh\left(\frac {\sqrt{\xi^2 + |\Delta|^2}}{2K_{b}T}\right)}{2\sqrt{\xi^2 + |\Delta|^2}}\,\mathrm d\xi $$
In order to see if my code is working I've tried to find the relation $Δ_{0}=1.76k_{B}T_{c}$, where $Δ_{0} = \Delta(0)$,  but I just can find it if I consider $K_{b}=1$. Can anybody help me? I' considering the simplest case as possible. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

lam = 0.17
Ec = 1000
Kb= 1.38064852e-23
from scipy.integrate import quad


#compute simpson integrate of a function
def simpson(f, a, b, N):
  if N%2 == 1:
    raise ValueError("N precisa ser par!")
  pares = 0
  impares = 0
  h = (b-a)/N
  for i in range(1, int(N/2)+1):
    impares += f(a + (2*i-1)*h)
  for i in range(1, int(N/2)):
    pares += f(a + 2*i*h) 
  return (h/3)*(f(a) + f(b) + 4*impares + 2*pares)

def f(E):
  return (lam*delta_in*np.tanh(np.sqrt(E**2 + abs(delta_in)**2)/(2*Kb*T)))/(2*np.sqrt((E**2 + abs(delta_in)**2)))

Kb= 1#boltzmann constant

#iterate until the difference beetween deltas is too small
delta_in = 10
T_vetor = np.linspace(0,30, 1000)
delta_fin_list =[]
for i in T_vetor:
  T=i
  delta_in = 1
  delta_fin = quad(f, -Ec, Ec)
  delta_in_list = [delta_in]
  while (abs(delta_in- delta_fin[0])>1e-6):
    delta_in = delta_fin[0]
    delta_fin = quad(f, -Ec, Ec)
    delta_in_list.append(delta_in)
  delta_fin_list.append(delta_fin[0])
```

I'm considering the simplest as possible for the integratio limits too.
I taught it could be problems in python's float decimal places limits.

Comment: I doubt anyone can really offer any help because your code is a mess. You need to clean that up. Some suggestions: (a) don't abuse global variables, instead pass variables to the arguments using the `args` parameter in `quad` and (b) write functions (with appropriate names!) instead of a loop that does most the work.

Comment: Given the comment above the main loop, it appears you are doing some sort of fixed point iteration to find the $\Delta$ s.t. it is equal to the integral term on the right. Are you certain that you will converge using $\Delta=f(E,\Delta,T)$ for all $T$? You might have a problem there, as many cases of fixed point iterations do *not* converge to a solution (perhaps consider something like Newton's method?)

Comment: Also, the "python's float decimal places limits" part is not going to be a problem, as whatever floating point issues are found there will also be found in any of the other IEEE-754 compliant languages.